# Reduce comment minimum length

Tags: discussion

I think it should be reduced from 15 to 3 characters. Sometimes you just want to reply with a "No." or "Yes."

What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

I don't want to encourage "yes"/"no" questions and answers.  Anything answered that easily doesn't belong on the site, and comments along those lines work better in chat than here.

Remember, the Stack Exchange isn't a forum.

Comment: Comments should clarify and enrich questions and answers. We have UP and DOWN vote buttons that adequately serve the need for "yes" and "no" responses.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with EAMann on that. We shouldn't encourage just yes/no responses. My mother gives me a right ear full if I just answer with yes/no answers. She is right to do so as its irritating as hell.

If you need to answer yes or no then that answer should come with a reason why or some follow up.

"Yes - this is because... blah blah blah"
"No - but have you tried....?"